# How to Identify a Close button in a In-App that is pushed to a application

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk

We are doing the in-app message design on SFMC, there is a close button on the UI message.
When we click on the close button its not closing the In-app its redirecting to the link that is given in the CTA button on the In-App.

Thanks in Advance !

Response in Mobile app:
InAppMessage(id=MzQ6MTE0OjA6aW8zekYyMlFFZXE0TnJpREExdm9BUQ, activityInstanceId=51a27c16-4227-418f-8bf0-1e15098c8875, priority=999, startDateUtc=Wed Feb 26 11:27:00 GMT+08:00 2020, endDateUtc=null, modifiedDateUtc=Wed Feb 26 11:25:34 GMT+08:00 2020, displayLimit=1, type=bannerTop, windowColor=0x99000000, displayDuration=-1, backgroundColor=0xFFFFFFFF, borderWidth=s, borderColor=0xFF000000, cornerRadius=m, layoutOrder=ImageTitleBody, media=Media(url=https://image.s50.example.jpg, size=e2e, altText=null, borderWidth=s, borderColor=0xFF000000, cornerRadius=s), title=null, body=TextField(text=sample, fontSize=s, fontColor=0xFF444444, alignment=beginning), closeButton=CloseButton(alignment=end), buttonConfiguration=twoUp, buttons=[])

Comment: Android, iOS or both? What version(s) of the SDK(s)? You have 1 CTA with a URL action and you're referring to the default close button in (typically) in the upper-right corner, correct? Also, if this problem is reproducible then please capture the InApp Message payload with the SDKs' `get state` method and paste the output here.

Comment: Yes correct. Its the button on the upper-right corner.

Comment: You need to open a support case through your AE or support contact.  I am an engineer on the Android SDK and I can tell you that this simply is not possible from within the SDK as it merely calls `finish()` when that button is pressed and is not re-assignable to anything.  I would love to work with you to see what is going on.  Please provide a Message ID when creating your support case to help us easily get to the message payload for which you are having a problem.

Comment: Hi Bill, I have added the response we get on the mobile app when we receive the In-app in Mobile app in the description of the ticket.

Comment: Again, please open a case.  The IAM JSON object you provided does not have any CTAs in the payload as can be seen here `buttons=[]`.  As such, there's no `urlAction` in your payload from which the SDK could act on no matter what/where you clicked which only lends to my suspicioun that you have misconfigured something in your handling of clicks.

Comment: Hey Bill, The issue we are facing is with the close button on the right top corner of the IN-App message. We have enabled the button in the front end but it does not work when we try to close the In-app in the mobile app

Comment: I understand completely.  1) there are no URLs in the REST response.  How exactly would the close button redirect to a URL that does not exist?  2) open a case.  Also, open a case.  Finally, open. a. case.